# Injecting logic between @Before and @Test execution with Spring and JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm writing some feature (test listener) called SqlCounter.
It's purpose — to count Real SQL queries during test execution.
If this count is bigger then special env property — test fails.

Problem is that: I have some logic in my @Before methods, which also run a lot of queries. What I need — is to clear my "SQL counter" actually after ALL "before" hooks (right before the start of the test method execution).

But ALL known to me ways (org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener:beforeTestMethod, org.junit.rules.TestWatcher:starting, org.junit.rules.TestRule:apply) execute BEFORE JUnit's @Before :(
Help me, please ;)

Update:
I want to clear this SQL counter NOT explicitly (in the every @Before) but in the some listener, which must be invoked right between @Before and @Test annotated methods

Comment: can you add the code that clears the SQL counter in your @Before method AFTER the set-up SQL has executed?

Comment: it's implemented with help of ttddyy/datasource-proxy (https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) like in this article — https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/02/01/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing (QueryCountHolder.clear();)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution of `@Rule`/`@Before`/`@Test` annotations sequence in JUnit depends on a Runner implementation. Let's say `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock` or `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock` looks like:

```
Statement statement = methodInvoker(frameworkMethod, testInstance);
statement = possiblyExpectingExceptions(frameworkMethod, testInstance, statement);
statement = withBefores(frameworkMethod, testInstance, statement);
...
statement = withRules...
```

Based on that I can propose the following implementation with overriding `methodInvoker` and adding new `@RightBeforeTest` annotation

```
package info.test;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(JUnit4AnnotationsSequenceTest.CustomSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class JUnit4AnnotationsSequenceTest
{
  private String value = null;

  @Before
  public void setUp()
  {
    value = "@Before.setUp";
  }

  @RightBeforeTest
  public void latestChance()
  {
    value = "@RightBeforeTest.latestChance"; 
  }

  @Test
  public void rightBeforeTestAnnotationExecutesAfterBeforeAnnotation()
  {
    assertEquals("@RightBeforeTest.latestChance", value);
  }

  public static class CustomSpringJUnit4ClassRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
  {
    public CustomSpringJUnit4ClassRunner(final Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError
    {
      super(clazz);
    }

    protected Statement methodInvoker(final FrameworkMethod method, final Object test)
    {
      return new RunBefores(
          super.methodInvoker(method, test),
          getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(RightBeforeTest.class),
          test);
    }
  }

  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  public @interface RightBeforeTest {}
}
```

[image: test result]

Comment: It's a miracle! Really Big-Big Thanks! ;)